# Using DisplayPort hubs, splitting the massive meta-screen

Tags: displayport, display

I've recently started a programming company with my girlfriend and we're doing a lot of pair programming. I'm looking into the various solutions for driving multiple external monitors from a MacBook Pro. It looks like the solutions are to either find a DisplayPort 2.0 monitor and daisy-chain them (too expensive / rare), use a USB video card (lol, lag), or use a DisplayPort hub.

The problem with DisplayPort hubs like [this one](http://accellcables.com/products/DisplayPort/DP/dp_dvi_multimonitor.htm) are that they apparently show up to the computer as one big display, X times as wide as each of the individuals. My question to you, AskDifferenters, is if there is a way to make the system believe that they are individual monitors, either in hardware or in software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Matrox TripleHead2Go includes their [Powerdesk driver](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/mac/powerdesk/) that can apparently send windows and the dock to specific displays. I'm not sure how far the illusion goes that they are indeed separate displays instead of the one logical display they represent.

Have you actually tried USB monitors? If used for coding and/or docs, I don't think their theoretical lack in bandwidth creates much of a practical problem. If you plan on gaming or watching videos on them, that's another matter. I wouldn't rule them out for ordinary work-type jobs without checking them out myself first.

Comment: +1 for USB monitors. I love coding with three equally large monitors (or 4 when doing serious code merging all week long) but a mac pro with multiple graphics cards is a lot more expensive than a MacBook Pro.